# Canvas.drawLines() does not draw anything on KitKat if the input array contains NaN values

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-4.4-kitkat

I've got a properly generated array of x-y pairs. Some of those values are NaN

The `Canvas.drawLines()` in ICS, JB 4.1 and LP 5.1 just ignores those values and skips them, drawing the rest of the lines, but for some reason KK does not draw anything in such cases. Any way to fix it?

Turning off antialiasing and hardware acceleration does not help

Answer (score 0):

Run a quick bit of code to remove all the NaN XY pairs. You could equally replace them with copies of the last valid XY pair, depending on how your code is working. You can always pretty efficiently fix these issues. But, if KitKat is doing that either set your app version above that or play ball. It's feeding it into the gpu and it doesn't have any documentation as to how it is required to handle NaN. It apparently messes with the tesselator which later only killed that one line segment but at kitkat would balk at the whole thing.

If you have x-y pairs with NaN just consider those improper. Loop and remove them, efficiently.

```
 public int nanDrop(int index) {
        int arrayIndex = index << 1;
        int returnIndex = index;
        int validPosition = 0;
        float mx, my;
        for (int pos = 0, s = count; pos < s; pos += 2) {
            mx = pointlist[pos];
            my = pointlist[pos + 1];
            if (pos == arrayIndex) returnIndex = validPosition >> 1;
            if (!Float.isNaN(mx)) {
                pointlist[validPosition] = mx;
                pointlist[validPosition + 1] = my;
                validPosition += 2;
            }
        }
        count = validPosition;
        return returnIndex;
    }
```